# signed apk not finding classes

Tags: android, apk, noclassdeffounderror

My app is working fine if I simply run eclipse with a real device. However, once I create a signed apk, the apk throws exception about `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. Basically, it loads the main activity fine. But when I click a button to load a second activity, it throws the exception.

Here is the exception. Again, the apk is not working after signing. Otherwise, the apk works fine. And no I have not activated proguard.

```
07-15 21:24:10.307: E/ACDB-LOADER(223): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -8
07-15 21:24:10.317: W/dalvikvm(19205): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b0aac8)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3735)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17961)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3730)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    ... 11 more
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.company.game.LoginActivity
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at com.company.game.WelcomeActivity.dispatchLoginActivity(WelcomeActivity.java:88)
07-15 21:24:10.327: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    ... 14 more
```

EDIT:

Also this may help: When it's the signed apk, the `application` section of `LogCat` for the app is blank.

Comment: since only when you sign the apk you are facing the issue so it could be related to the signing process itself. How you are signing the apk?

Comment: Eclipse guides me through the signing process.